# The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type , but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am trying to create a code-behind for my `_Layout.cshtml` [Razor Pages](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-3.1) in an ASP.NET Core web application. I named the page as `_Layout.cshtml.cs`

[image]

This is the code for `_Layout.cshtml.cs`:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace xx.WebApp.Pages._Shared
{
    public class _LayoutModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly GraphProfileClient _graphProfileClient;

        public string UserPhoto { get; private set; }

        public _LayoutModel(GraphProfileClient graphProfileClient)
        {
            _graphProfileClient = graphProfileClient;
        }

        public async Task OnGetAsync()
        {
            UserPhoto = await _graphProfileClient.GetUserProfileImage();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code for `_Layout.cshtml`

[image]

But when I ran it, I got this error:

> "The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type
> 'xx.WebApp.Pages.Pages_Logout', but this ViewDataDictionary instance
> requires a model item of type 'xx.WebApp.Pages._Shared._LayoutModel'."

Comment: A Layout is not a page, it doesn't have handlers. It's only a view. A layout *can* have a model type, but it must be assignable from the model type of *all* views that use this layout. In other words, if all your page models implement the same interface, you can use that model type in your layout. Or you can check the type dynamically `@if(Model is IUser u) { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

You could try as below:

```
public class _LayoutModel : PageModel
    {
        public string Title { get; set; } = "";

        public  virtual void OnGet()
        {
            Title = "Hi";
        }

    }
```

On the layout page:

```
@model  _LayoutModel
```

Other pagemodel:

```
public class IndexModel : _LayoutModel
    {
        
        public string PageName { get; set; }

        public IndexModel( )
        {
             
        }

        public override void OnGet()
        {
            PageName = "Index";
            base.OnGet();
        }
    }
```

On the layout page, I called:

```
@Model.Title
```

On the Index Page, I called both:

```
@Model.Title and @Model.PageName
```

Now it works well:

[image]